# Passar CSV para Classe C++

Tags: c++, csv

Tenho uma classe que que encho com um csv e quando tento adicionar um nova linha no ficheiro dá-me erro de alocação de memoria em seguida o codigo:

```
#pragma once
#include "Produto.h"

class GerirProduto {
    public:
        GerirProduto();
        void adicionarProduto(int id,string nome, int stock, double precoCusto, double iva);
        void removerProduto(string nome);
        void modificarProduto(string nome,int novoStock, double novoPrecoCusto, double novoIva);
        void mostrarProdutos();

    private:
        bool verificaNoCsv(int id,string nome);
        void guardarInformacoes();
        Produto* item;
        int numItem;
};
```

Gerirproduto.cpp

```
#include "GerirProduto.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

bool GerirProduto::verificaNoCsv(int id, string nome){
    ifstream arquivo("produtos.csv");
    string linha;
    while (getline(arquivo, linha)) {
        stringstream ss(linha);
        string idCSV, nomeCSV, stock, precoCusto, iva;
        getline(ss, idCSV, ',');
        getline(ss, nomeCSV, ',');
        getline(ss, stock, ',');
        getline(ss, precoCusto, ',');
        getline(ss, iva, ',');
        if (nomeCSV == nome|| idCSV == to_string(id)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void GerirProduto::guardarInformacoes() {
    fstream arquivo("produtos.csv", ios::out | ios::app);  // Abra o arquivo no modo ios::app
    if (!arquivo.is_open()) {
        arquivo.open("produtos.csv", ios::out);  // Abra o arquivo no modo ios::out se ele não existir
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <numItem; i++) {
        arquivo << item[i].getId() << "," << item[i].getNome() << "," << item[i].getStock() << "," << item[i].getPrecoCusto() << "," << item[i].getIva() << endl;
    }
    arquivo.close();
}

GerirProduto::GerirProduto() {

    ifstream arquivo("produtos.csv");
    if (!arquivo.is_open()) {
        cout << "Arquivo de produtos não encontrado." << endl;
        return;
    }
    string linha;
    numItem = 0;

    //Ler quantas linhas tem o csv
    while (getline(arquivo, linha)) {
        numItem++;
    }
    numItem++;

    arquivo.close();

    item = new Produto[numItem];

    arquivo.open("produtos.csv");
    numItem = 0;

    while (getline(arquivo, linha)) {
        stringstream ss(linha);
        string idCSV, nomeCSV, stock, precoCusto, iva;
        getline(ss, idCSV, ',');
        getline(ss, nomeCSV, ',');
        getline(ss, stock, ',');
        getline(ss, precoCusto, ',');
        getline(ss, iva, ',');

        int id = stoi(idCSV);
        int stockValue = stoi(stock);
        double precoCustoValue = stod(precoCusto);
        double ivaValue = stod(iva);
        item[numItem] = Produto(id, nomeCSV, stockValue, precoCustoValue, ivaValue);
        numItem++;
    }
    arquivo.close();
}

void GerirProduto::adicionarProduto( int id, string nome, int stock, double precoCusto, double iva){
    if (!verificaNoCsv(id, nome)) {

        numItem++;
        Produto* newItem = new Produto[numItem];

        for (int i = 0; i < numItem; i++) {
            newItem[i] = item[i];
        }

        newItem[numItem] = Produto(id, nome, stock, precoCusto, iva);
        numItem++;

        if (item != nullptr) {
            delete[] item;
        }

        item = newItem;

        guardarInformacoes();
    }
    else {
        cout << "ID ou Nome ja existem!!\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu programa cancela porque está errado. E é normal até aí. Mas a razão dele cancelar envolve um grande número de erros conceituais. As coisas simplesmente não são assim nessas linguagens. Você tem um professor? Um bom livro? Um plano? Procure ter os 3.

Em `C++` --- como em *java*, *javascript*, *Python* e um grande número de linguagens --- existe o conceito de classe e o conceito de instância. Não deve escrever programas nessas linguagens enquanto não tiver esse conceito claro.

Vou deixar uma explicação passo a passo aqui porque pode ajudar num primeiro momento a ver  essa relação classe x instância, em especial se está ao mesmo tempo escrevendo programas simples em `C` ou `Assembler` ou outra que não tenha essas coisas.

Essa é sua classe, direto de sua questão como apresentada:

```
class GerirProduto {
    public:
        GerirProduto();
        void adicionarProduto(int id,string nome, int stock, double precoCusto, double iva);
        void removerProduto(string nome);
        void modificarProduto(string nome,int novoStock, double novoPrecoCusto, double novoIva);
        void mostrarProdutos();

    private:
        bool verificaNoCsv(int id,string nome);
        void guardarInformacoes();
        Produto* item;
        int numItem;
};
```

Isso sugere que você queria ter uma classe `Produto` e que tal coisa teria `id`, `nome`, `stock`, `precoCusto` e `iva`.

E onde está isso? Não existem.

E onde iriam parar esses produtos? A julgar pelo código iriam parar num array `private` chamado `item`, e a quantia num dado momento seria representada por `numItem`:

```
        Produto* item;
        int numItem;
```

No código `item` é `Produto*` e pode apontar para um `Produto`. Só um.

Se você escrever

```
    item = new Produto[numItem];
```

Como está em seu programa, vai funcionar uma única vez, se `numItem` for `0`. Isso porque em `C++` como em `C` o endereço do primeiro elemento de um vetor pode ser acessado assim --- *array to pointer decay*.

Alem desse único vai ter que alocar memória para o ponteiro para cada novo elemento. `new Produto()` apenas aloca um novo `Produto`, uma instancia da classe, com seus valores e funções (métodos).

#### A classe `Produto`

```
class Produto
{
   public:
   private:
    int    id;
    string nome;
    int    stock;
    double preco_custo;
    double iva;
};
```

Se um produto é assim, cada novo produto deve ter esses campos. Podem vir de qualquer lugar ou de nenhum. Sempre vão estar lá. Podem ter valores indefinidos, mas estarão em cada instância da classe.

#### criando um `Produto`

Isso é feito explicitamente ou implicitamente por um construtor. Isso seria a idéia de

```
void GerirProduto::adicionarProduto(
    int id, string nome, int stock, double precoCusto,
    double iva)
```

em seu programa original. Só que não é bem assim em `C++`.

Você pode ter vários construtores, e todos tem o mesmo nome: o da Classe. Isso é polimorfismo e é um dos pilares dessas linguagems orientadas a objetos.

Esse seria um trivial construtor:

```
Produto::Produto(
    int id, string nome, int stock, double precoCusto,
    double iva)
{
    id         = id;
    nome       = nome;
    stock      = stock;
    precoCusto = precoCusto;
    iva        = iva;
}
```

E um programa assim

```
#include "Produto.h"

int main(void)
{ 
    Produto um = Produto(2, "Produto X", 1, 42., 4.2);
    return 0;
}
```

Já rodaria e ajudaria a entender melhor as coisas: `um` é um instância de `Produto`.

Como era de se esperar, há uma notação mais simples para isso:

```
Produto::Produto(
    int um, string nm, int stock, double preco,
    double iva)
    : id(um), stock(stock), preco_custo(preco), iva(iva){};
```

Usando `:` precedendo uma lista de campos que vão ser apenas copiados dos argumentos.

#### o construtor padrão

O construtor padrão é um que não tem argumentos, e podia ser algo assim para esse exemplo:

```
Produto::Produto()
{
    id         = -1;
    nome       = "";
    stock      = 0;
    precoCusto = 0.;
    iva        = 0.;
}
```

Exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Produto.h"

int main(void)
{ 
    Produto um = Produto(2, "Produto X", 1, 42., 4.2);
    Produto outro = Produto();
    std::cout << "id de 'um' = " << um.id << endl;
    std::cout << "id de 'outro' = " << outro.id << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

mostraria

```
id de 'um' = 2
id de 'outro' = -1
```

E se vê que foi usado o construtor padrão para criar o segundo. E ele será usado para inicializar qualquer instância de container, implicitamente.

**Exemplo:**

```
    Produto prd[30];
```

O construtor padrão vai ser chamado para TODOS esses 30 elementos do array. Todos os campos vão ter os valores como definidos no construtor padrão.

#### a noção de *container*

métodos como

```
        void adicionarProduto(int id,string nome, int stock, double precoCusto, double iva);
        void removerProduto(string nome);
        void modificarProduto(string nome,int novoStock, double novoPrecoCusto, double novoIva);
        void mostrarProdutos();

    private:
        bool verificaNoCsv(int id,string nome);
        void guardarInformacoes();
```

Envolvem outra entidade que não é o `Produto`: é uma coleção de produtos. Em *java* são chamadas assim, [collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html). Em `C++` são chamados *containers* como visto [em português na documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/cpp/standard-library/stl-containers?view=msvc-170).

`C++` oferece vetor, array, lista, fila, pilha. mapa, conjunto e outros containers, e todos tem claro o mesmo paradigma. Tem tamanho ajustável e o tamanho faz parte do container. E tem tamanho variável.

Pode ter um container de qualquer coisa, de qualquer classe. Um vetor de `Produto` seria algo simples para seu caso e pode ter um exemplo do uso aqui. O programa abaixo pega os produtos do último exemplo, coloca em um vetor e mostra as `id` na tela:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Produto.h"

int main(void)
{ 
    Produto um = Produto(2, "Produto X", 1, 42., 4.2);
    Produto outro = Produto();
    std::cout << "id de 'um' = " << um.id << endl;
    std::cout << "id de 'outro' = " << outro.id << "\n";

    auto catalogo = std::vector<Produto>{um, outro};
    for (auto p : catalogo)
        std::cout << "id " << p.id << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

E mostra

```
id de 'um' = 2
id de 'outro' = -1
id 2
id -1
```

Claro que seu objetivo pode ser justamente escrever tal *container* e assim usaria uma Classe`. Algo assim seria o comum:

```
// catalogo.h
#pragma once
#include <vector>

#include "Produto.h"
class Catalogo
{
   private:
    unsigned size;

   public:
    Catalogo();
    int    Adicionar(Produto);
    int    Remover(int id);
    int    Remover(string nome);
    int    Listar();
    size_t get_size();

   private:
    vector<Produto> Prd;
};
```

Eis a implementação simples usada, que já pode compilar

```
#include "Catalogo.h"

Catalogo::Catalogo() : size(0){}

int Catalogo::Adicionar(Produto novo)
{
    Prd.push_back(novo);
    size++;
    return 0;
}
int Catalogo::Remover(int id) { return -1; }
int Catalogo::Remover(string nome) { return -1; }

int Catalogo::Listar()
{
    std::cout << "    Catalogo tem " << size
              << " produtos:\n\n";
    for (auto p: Prd ) std::cout << "id " << p.id << "\n";
    return 0;
}

size_t Catalogo::get_size() { return size_t(size); }
```

E `main` para um exemplo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Produto.h"
#include "Catalogo.h"

int main(void)
{ 
    Produto um = Produto(2, "Produto X", 1, 42., 4.2);
    Produto outro = Produto();
    std::cout << "id de 'um' = " << um.id << endl;
    std::cout << "id de 'outro' = " << outro.id << "\n";

    auto catalogo = std::vector<Produto>{um, outro};
    for (auto p : catalogo)
        std::cout << "id " << p.id << "\n";

    Catalogo cat;
    cat.Adicionar(um);
    cat.Adicionar(outro);
    std::cout << "    main: Catalogo tem " << cat.get_size()
              << " produtos\n";
    cat.Listar();

    return 0;
}
```

Esse programa mostra algumas coisas que precisa entender:

- classe e instância em `C++`
- composição
- polimorfismo
- algo da sintaxe
- um container simples

Mas é um exemplo mínimo. `C++` é uma linguagem enorme e complexa. mas talvez a melhor que existe para compor modelos e abstrair coisas.